Specify the correct output directory for minted
I am using the minted package to put code fragments in my documents. I usually redirect the output to a build directory using --output-directory=build in the command line. Accordingly, I use \usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}. However, I recently started to use VSCode with the Latex Workshop extension, and I noticed something important: I have a lot of different documents from different courses and assignments. This means I end up with a lot of build directories floating everywhere which isn't nice. I'd prefer all the outputs to go into a build in my workspace root and then divided into subdirectories based on the documents. Setting this with Latex Workshop was easy. I just set "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%WORKSPACE_FOLDER%/build/%RELATIVE_DIR%" which changed the path passed to --output-directory. However, minted obviously wasn't aware of this change so using \usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted} means its outputs are still relative to the documents:

The problem is I don't have access to the macros from Latex Workshop for minted so my only option is to manually set the paths \usepackage[outputdir=../../build/Electro/HW1...]{minted}
which is terrible. I couldn't find how to set outputdir in a nice way. Is there a way to tell minted to use the build directory of the workspace like the rest of the output?
I don't want to use absolute paths since it's not portable, and I don't want to use parent directories (like ..) because it's very fragile if I move files around.

Using build folders as such can already cause a lot of problems, but using a common build folder for all document might end up disastrous in case some files have the same name.

Which is why the build is further divided by the relative paths. having two files with the same name is fine as long as they're in different directories.
